# Need to insert Stack into List

Tags: c++, arrays, list, stack

I have a stack of numbers from 0-17 and i need to put that stack into List on first position how could i use function Insert? or do i have to somehow change Insert ?

This is my struct of List

```
struct List
{
    int data;
    struct List *Next;
};
```

and this is how i have my Insert

```
void Insert(List **pps, int prvek)
{
    List *ps;
    ps = (List *)malloc(sizeof(List));
    if (!ps) {
        return;
    }
    ps->data = prvek;
    ps->Next = *pps;
    *pps = ps;
}
```

Comment: you forgot to add a tag for the programming lang

Comment: define what you mean with "I have a stack of..."; I think it's unclear. Also, what *exactly* do you want to insert into what? What kind of items does your list contain?

Comment: A list where you only insert and remove at the front is a stack.

Comment: Your insert function looks fine to me , what problem are you facing ?

Comment: I think that this List can just be used a stack as it is putting a new thing at the top; so this `Insert` in list is doing a `Push` on stack.

Comment: Standard Warning : Please [do not cast](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917) the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.

Comment: Where did you copy this code? AND: please get the formatting right!

Comment: It's not very clear what you want to achieve.  You can't have all 18 numbers "on the first position" at the head of the list.  The `List` only holds integers, so you cannot put a whole 'stack' on it at all.  A stack is a [LIFO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LIFO_(computing)) storage system, so what order would the have to be added to the list: eldest at the head or newest? Please could you provide some code to show what you've tried, as well as the implementation of your 'stack'?

Comment: @Kunal I need to insert into List this first Stack and then i will from that first stack take for example 4 numbers (14,15,16,17)and put it into another stuck and that second stack will be on 2nd position in that List.

Comment: @Kasik, so you want to make list/array of stack ? like [first stack, second stack, ..., ... ] ?

Comment: @MikeofSST i need a pointer in that list on that stack of numbers and in a code for now i only generate that stack full of numbers and i wrote comments here what exactly i need :)

Comment: @Kasik, then you need a Vector, which holds the stack pointer(which is your current List struct). Once you create a Stack insert the head pointer to Vector.

Comment: As you're using C++, have you looked at using `std::List<T>` ?  You could declare `std:List<stack>` variable and use that.

Comment: @MikeofSST well i have forbidden to use classes -_- so how exactly can i use it?

Answer (score 0):

So from your comment, I understood that you need a List of stacks. Your current code already is able to create stack. You can store that stack to [vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/).

Like below,

```
#include <vector>

std::vector<List*> stackList;

stackList.push_back(firstStack);
stackList.push_back(secondStack);
```

....

Comment: @Kunal It gives me this error :/ at `stackList.push_back(T);`
IntelliSense: no instance of overloaded function "std::vector<_Ty, _Alloc>::push_back [with _Ty=List *, _Alloc=std::allocator<List *>]" matches the argument list argument types are: (Stack)
 object type is: std::vector<List *, std::allocator<List *>>